# How can I get NSWindows to apply my custom colors?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nswindow

There are many windows in my application, and I don't want to add an attribute observation to each one.

I have defined some NSColor objects, which are adapted to the theme I designed for App. NSColor can return the corresponding color according to the theme I designed for App.

But I don't know how I should refresh all the windows, let them re-render the view, and let my custom NSColor look like the standard system colors of NSColor. labelColor.

I noticed that every time I switch MacOS Appearance, all NSWindows refresh the view, which makes NSColor. labelColor produce different colors.

So I want to ask how I should refresh all NSWindows and just let them apply my NSColor, just like the new color of NSColor. labelColor in Dark Mode.

Note that I'm not asking about switching between bright and dark themes. What I want to ask is to refresh the views of NSWindows so that they can re-apply a new NSColor.

thx

Comment: The easiest solution, assuming this isn't something that happens often, would be to simply walk all of the windows in your app and force them to redraw. That's essentially what the appearance manager does when you switch from light to dark mode.

Comment: @JamesBucanek What do you mean is that I should go through all the windows and all the sub-views in the windows? If only traversing windows is not possible, this may include their child views.

Comment: I believe that all you'd need to do is walk your windows (see `NSApplication.orderedWindows`) and set the `needsDisplay` property on the top-level content view of each window to cause it, and all of its visible subviews, to redraw.

Comment: Even if you do need to recursively set `needsDisplay` on every subview, that's a trivial loop. Post again if you get stuck.